# Are there any good example / sample / demo app for SendBird?

Tags: sendbird

I am trying to build my iOS application and having hard time finding resources.

Can anyone that used SendBird before share useful resources that I can refer to?

Answer (score 1):

You can test out SendBird features on the Sample Website.

They also have sample projects for iOS, Android, JavaScript (Web), Unity, and Xamarin.

iOS (Objective-C and Swift): https://github.com/sendbird/SendBird-iOS

Android: https://github.com/sendbird/SendBird-Android

Unity: https://github.com/sendbird/SendBird-Unity

JavaScript (Web): https://github.com/sendbird/SendBird-JavaScript

Xamarin: https://github.com/sendbird/SendBird-Xamarin